# Scrape traffic data with Selenium that require login

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I need to scrape Authority score, Organic Search Traffic, Backlinks from burton.com using Selenium.

below script gives some errors
[Semrush image to be scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oiya.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

url = 'https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/?q=burton.com&searchType=domain' #your url
options = Options() #set up options
options.add_argument('--headless') #add --headless mode to options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)

#note: executable_path will depend on where your chromedriver.exe is located

driver.get(url) #get response
driver.implicitly_wait(1) #wait to load content
elements = driver.find_element("xpath", '//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]') #grab that stuff you wanted?  

for e in elements: print(e.get_attribute('text').strip()) #print text fields

driver.quit() #close the driver when you're done
```

### **Below is my error on Visual studio code**
Semrush needs login with a free trial to see above data, does it create the problem here.

---

```
PS C:\Users\akein> & C:/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/akein/OneDrive/Desktop/aaa.py
c:\Users\akein\OneDrive\Desktop\aaa.py:12: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
c:\Users\akein\OneDrive\Desktop\aaa.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50030/devtools/browser/6a717a35-4404-46d0-b2df-fa1ba06fbb3d
[1008/234714.670:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "limitPopup", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.006:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'B', "Bad Request
" is not valid JSON", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.058:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.059:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)       
[1008/234715.059:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.060:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)       
[1008/234715.060:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.060:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)       
[1008/234715.068:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.068:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1008/234715.433:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "SSO Frontend. You are using old value for defaultActiveTab parameter.
      Please use loginForm instead of login.
      For more information see the documentation.", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\akein\OneDrive\Desktop\aaa.py", line 18, in <module>
    elements = driver.find_element("xpath", '//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]') #grab that stuff you wanted?
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.103)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00D71ED3+2236115]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D092F1+1807089]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C166FD+812797]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C455DF+1005023]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C457CB+1005515]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C77632+1209906]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C61AD4+1120980]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C759E2+1202658]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C618A6+1120422]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C3A73D+960317]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C3B71F+964383]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0101E7E2+2743074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010108D4+2685972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E02BAA+532202]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E01990+527568]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D1080C+1837068]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D14CD8+1854680]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D14DC5+1854917]
        Ordinal0 [0x00D1ED64+1895780]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7666FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77427A6E+238]
```

a-- ---- ---- --- ---a --- -- -- --- --b ----- ---- -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

- - - - - - - - - - - -- - - -s- - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - - - --

Comment: Are you logging in with chrome/selenium, before running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]"` is caused since the above xpath is not present on the page

Firstly on visiting the site we need to `Log In`

Post that to extract `Authority score, Organic Search Traffic, Backlinks`  form site we can use the `label` for those fields and find the values as a `relative value` to the field (since the value field does not have any specific id)

Your solution would look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

url = 'https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/? 
q=burton.com&searchType=domain' #your url
options = Options() #set up options
options.add_argument('--headless') #add --headless mode to options
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument('--log-level=3') # Only display fatal logs and remove info logs from selenium output console
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options) 
driver.get(url) #get response
# Login to website
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Log In')]").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("your usename")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("your password")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Log in')]").click()
# Ensure user is logged in
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 
"use")))
 # Add label of the field for which details need to be fetched
 tags = ['Authority Score', 'Organic search traffic', 'Backlinks']
for tag in tags:
   print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//span[contains(text(), '{tag}')]/ancestor::div[@direction='column']/descendant::a[@data-at='main-number']/span").text)
 driver.quit() #close the driver when you're done
```

`The below logs are not error in the selenium script what it is displaying is the browser console message when you visit the above url i.e https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/? q=burton.com&searchType=domain`

`You can view those messages manually as well by navigating to the url and viewing the console(Right click on the page and click inspect element)`

[image: Refer image]

`If you do not want them to pop in your selenium script console you can add the following chrome argument to only show logs when there is an error on the site  options.add_argument('--log-level=3'))`

Have update the answer with the same

```
    PS C:\Users\akein> & C:/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/akein/OneDrive/Desktop/stackhelp1.py
c:\Users\akein\OneDrive\Desktop\stackhelp1.py:15: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
c:\Users\akein\OneDrive\Desktop\stackhelp1.py:15: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
```

##### These are console messages from the webpage

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61855/devtools/browser/2d0fea02-dfc1-499b-be1c-698558028f9b
[1009/140232.922:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140232.923:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)       
[1009/140232.923:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140232.923:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)       
[1009/140232.924:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140232.924:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)       
[1009/140232.931:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140232.932:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)       
[1009/140233.435:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "limitPopup", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140234.006:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'B', "Bad Request
" is not valid JSON", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140234.520:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "SSO Frontend. You are using old value for defaultActiveTab parameter.
      Please use loginForm instead of login.
      For more information see the documentation.", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140235.753:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140235.754:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140235.755:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140235.755:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140235.756:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140235.756:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140236.107:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Munchkin.init("%s") options: 519-IIY-869 [object Object]", source: https://www.semrush.com/static/spa.vendors.chunk.87dbdd75124bc5d6b456.js (2)
[1009/140237.151:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Your client application uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.", source: https://www.semrush.com/static/spa.vendors.chunk.87dbdd75124bc5d6b456.js (2)
[1009/140241.967:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.967:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.968:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.968:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.968:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.969:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.994:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  prop [[getByName]] is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140241.994:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "dataLayerProxy:  method call is not supported", source: https://www.semrush.com/__static__/webpack/data_layer_proxy.bce1755d.js (1)
[1009/140244.394:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Munchkin.init("%s") options: 519-IIY-869 [object Object]", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140245.412:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "FirstScreenHeroData222 summary_organic", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140245.412:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "FirstScreenHeroData222 summary_adwords", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
[1009/140245.708:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "FirstScreenHeroData222 summary_backlinks", source: https://static.semrush.com/domain-overview/vendor.2365e1d7f296adbbe3c8.chunk.js (2)
```

##### This is the actual output

```
72
1.6M
74.1M
```

Comment: I added working username and password to check the result, it gives the output but with an error

Comment: Hi @Joh Burton can you provide the error details

Comment: Hi @Darshan Shah, I have already modified your reply and added error code under your same reply

Comment: Hi @John Burton The below logs are not error in the selenium script what it is displaying is the browser console message when you visit the above url i.e https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/? q=burton.com&searchType=domain

Comment: If you do not wish to view those logs you can add the line `options.add_argument('--log-level=3') # Only display fatal logs and remove info logs from selenium output console`. Have updated the answer with the same and the explanation for it

Comment: To know more about it refer the page https://joshuatz.com/posts/2020/selenium-webdriver-disabling-chrome-logging-messages/. Also @John Burton can you approve the answer if it solves the issue

Comment: Hi @John Burton can you check the above answer

Comment: I'm happy with this,

Comment: @John Burton can you approve the answer

Comment: Hey thanks, I approved your answer, kindly point where I'm wrong below. I wanted to save output in a csv file but the output is weired. I wanted output in one raw with comma seperated. for tag in tags:
   print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//span[contains(text(), '{tag}')]/ancestor::div[@direction='column']/descendant::a[@data-at='main-number']/span").text)

   with open('output.csv', 'w') as data_file:
    writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter='\n')
    writer.writerows(tags)

driver.quit() #close the driver when you're done

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in the page first, then use XPath to find the element, or you can attach to existing opening website page. For attaching to existing browser, you can use clicknium.

```
from clicknium import clicknium as cc
# first install chrome extension
cc.chrome.extension.install()
# then attach to browser with url, use wildcard(*) if part of the url may change
tab = cc.chrome.attach_by_title_url(url="https://www.semrush.com/analytics/overview/? q=burton.com&searchType=domain*")
elements = tab.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href="/info/burton.com+(by+organic)"]')
```